# What does vector::reserve do?

Tags: c++, vector

What does `vector::reserve` actually do since trying to access its data is an error?

```
vector<int> v.reserve(10);
v[4] = 22;
```

**if this allocated space it shouldn't be an error in the first place.. how can it 'reserve' space if it doesn't even allocate it?** How can the OS be informed that it has to allocate space for the vector?

Comment: Didn't have money to renew subscription to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)?

Comment: @dean That link answers the question. Are you getting a segfault (memory wasn't allocated) or a failed assertion (vector didn't let you access uninitialized memory)?

Comment: @101010 read the bold text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reserve` *reserves* memory for growing the vector, with out changing it's `size()`. So in your case, `[4]` is still an invalid index.

While the vector will grow to a size as needed, there's a significant tradeoff between growing in large vs. small chunks: large chunks make expensive reallocations and copies less common, but also waste memory.

`reserve(10)` reserves memory so you can e.g. `push_back` 10 elements without having a reallocation.

---

When to use: if you are adding elements to a vector in multiple steps, and you know ahead the amount of elements - or even if you have a good guess -  use `reserve` to prepare the vector for accepting that many elements, and reduce the number of allocations necessary.

The amount reserved is called capacity - and can be queried using `.capacity()`.

Comment: I'm tempted to say that it does almost nothing. It gives certain guarantees about iterator invalidation, and may affect the performance of the program, but `reserve` it self doesn't have any noticeable side effects.

Comment: @Dean: No. Reserve always allocates contiguous memory, never anything else.

Comment: Oh.. so is it writing to my_vector[4] still an error even for non-object types like int? (things that don't require construction)

Comment: @Dean: yes. the object is neither constructed nor accessible. Note that `.at(index)` is range-checked, so an invalid index throws an exception. for `operator[]`, an invalid index is **undefined behavior** (even though implementations might not mind after a reserve)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Well... IIRC it is guaranteed that growing to `size<=capacity` (e.g. by inserting or appending) will not invalidate existing iterators, which is a big thing. Furthermore, performance is observably affected - both in terms of Big-O and wall time. OTOH, yeah, I see where you are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

vector::reserve allocate the memory but the size of the vector not change (even if the size of reserve < current size of the vector).
Use vector::resize for allocate and change the size.